# Getting an error when I run NPM live-server

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-live-server

Here's the server I'm using, https://www.npmjs.com/package/live-server.  However, when I try to use `~/.live-server.json` as the configuration file, I always fail...  Here's what I have in the file, and it's very simple.

```
{
   port: "8001"
}
```

Then I have this error when I run `live-server`

```
undefined:2
   port: "8001"
   ^    

SyntaxError: Unexpected token p
    at Object.parse (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/live-server/live-server.js:17:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:136:18)
    at node.js:963:3
```

I don't know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property names in JSON must be quoted (JSON is not JavaScript):

```
{
   "port": "8001"
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried "port": 8001, but not both of them.

Comment: `{ "port": 8001 }` is valid JSON. The difference is that `8001` is a number value and `"8001"` is a  string value, like in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
{
    "port": 8001
}
```

Add explanation: well, in JSON, name should always double quoted, and value should also be double quoted, except number (if you double quote a number, it becomes a string). Like this:

```
{
    "name1": "stringValue",
    "name2": aNumber
}
```

Comment: add more details to it...possibly an explanation